# how to get top and bottom margin exactly same irrespective of content.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm making a tableView in which cell height is dynamic according to content. So when there is more content for cell then top and bottom margin of the cell is more and if there is less content for any particular cell then the top and bottom margin is too less but I want same margin for everyone irrespective of content.

[image]   [image] [image]  [image]

I'm talking about first cell in which margin is just random (based on content), i want that top and bottom margin to same any number of content. I'm not using Custom cell.

Any help would be really appreciative, I have given lot of time on this. If u want my code, i can past it here..

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSString *session_name = [self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"session_name"];
        NSString *venue = [session_name stringByAppendingString:[self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"venue"]];
        NSString *tmp_name_venue = [session_time stringByAppendingString:venue];


        if(![self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"speakers"] || ![[self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"speakers"] isEqual:@""])
        {
            NSString *speaker_label = @"Speakers: ";
            NSString *speakers = [[NSString alloc]init];
            speakers = [self.parentDetailArray valueForKey:@"speakers"];
            speakers = [speaker_label stringByAppendingString:speakers];
            tmp_name_venue = [speakers stringByAppendingString:tmp_name_venue];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", tmp_name_venue);
       CGSize detailTextViewSize = [tmp_name_venue sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:18]constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX)lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];

        if(detailTextViewSize.height <37)
        {
            return 40;
        }
        if(detailTextViewSize.height >tmp_name_venue.length)
        {
            return detailTextViewSize.height;
        }
        else
        {
            detailTextViewSize.height = [tmp_name_venue length];//Here i'm just attempting to get the margin right.

            return detailTextViewSize.height;
        }


    }
```

Comment: it would be better if you paste some code here.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code for that.

Comment: as I understand you want to have first and last cell with same height - is it right? and height of middle cells is not interesting.. 

...... if so, when you need to calculate all heights and assign it to cells outside this method. and mind about if height of all cells is less than table height, here will need to add height to top and bottom cells to cover whole table height

Comment: No. i want change only in first cell not in last cell. I want empty space to be same above and below to the text, irrespective of content. As you can see in first the empty space above text and below text is varying according to content.

Comment: mm.. so in fact you want to center cell content inside the cell (and maybe expand cell height for more margins)?

Comment: Hmmm. You almost got it. i'll give an example, Say in first cell content is centered and it has 7px from top and 7px from bottom. So in any case (even the content in cell is very less or too much) i want that top and bottom margin to be 7px. It shouldn't vary with content. I hope now you will get it correctly..

Comment: is my answer below ok for you? don't know is I helped you.

Comment: it does gave me an idea to think differently but i chose to do this slightly different way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my last comment is right, when there is the answer for your problem. There is no simpliest way to position cell content if cell resize. So I found this solution ok for me. I create the cell in simple way, without any margins or so on, and after creation was ok - I have all sizes and can manipulate it.

First of all you need to create cell and calculate or set margins you want

```
....
// place there cells init (not inside heightForRowAtIndexPath)
// someway you have firstCell object representing first cell in table
CGFloat marginHeight = 10;
[self hierarchyItemsReposition:firstCell withTopShift:marginHeight];
[firstCell setFrame:CGRectMake(firstCell.frame.origin.x, firstCell.frame.origin.y, firstCell.frame.size.width, firstCell.frame.size.height+marginHeight*2)];
...

- (void)hierarchyItemsReposition:(UIView *)cell withTopShift:(CGFloat)shift
{
    for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews)
    {
        [subview setFrame:CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, subview.frame.origin.y+shift, subview.frame.size.width, subview.frame.size.height)];
        [self hierarchyItemsReposition:subview withTopShift:shift];
    }
}
```

I simply iterate through all subviews in this cell and shift it to needed position.

I place the starting point outside the heightForRowAtIndexPath, because it this case all other cells frames calculates in right way and if you want to work with it in future it will work ok.